# how to use image storage on softlayer like AWS s3(bucket)

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

1. Hi i am going to use Softlayer Server for my web application
2. I also wants to store image and videos on the Softlayer bucket. But i
   don't know how to use this service. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can see documentation here:
http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/

You can start with this doc
http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/introduction-object-storage

This could help you to work with Softlayer object storage through REST
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/Managing-SoftLayer-Object-Storage-Through-REST-APIs

here more documentation to work via API
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/objectstorageapi

Regards

Answer (score 1):

be aware now Softlayer as S3 compatible object storage ( handles bucket an so on) 
All information are here :
https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-operations.html

API details is here :

https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-api-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to choose Object Storage S3 API, after that you will be able to use it exactly like you use AWS S3 because both use standard S3 API, so you can use [any AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/) to access and perform operations on your object storage bucket.

When I worked on a Laravel app I just needed to install [aws-sdk-php-laravel](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel) to make things work, that's whole story.